# ¿Por qué no me envia el formulario a la base de datos?

Tags: java, android

Quiero enviar información de un formulario a mi base de datos para crear un login. Sin embargo, no se envían los datos y tampoco origina error. ¿Me podrían colaborar?

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button botonRegistrarse;
EditText TextoNombres, TextoApellidos, TextoCedula, TextoTelefono1, TextoTelefono2, TextoDirecion;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle saveInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    botonRegistrarse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    TextoNombres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombres);
    TextoApellidos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.apellidos);
    TextoCedula = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cedula);
    TextoTelefono1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefono1);
    TextoTelefono2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefono2);
    TextoDirecion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.direccion);

    botonRegistrarse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new EnvioPOST().execute("http://naikino.com/pizzeria/php/registrar.php");
        }
    });
}

private class EnvioPOST extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    //el metodo doInBackground para hacer en segundo plano
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //los parametros son pasados de la ejecucion execute(): url[0] es la url.
        try {

            //url[0] es la url y el 0 indica que vamos ha usar medoto GET
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "No se puede recuperar la pagina web. URL puede ser incorrecto.";

        }
    }

    //onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    Log.i("URL", "" + myurl);
    myurl = myurl.replace(" ", "%20"); /// Cambiamos espacios por %20
    InputStream is = null;
    String respuestaComoString = null;
    // Mostrar solo los primeros 500 carapteres del contenido
    // recuperado de la pagina web.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milisegundos */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milisegundos */);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        JSONObject variablesMetodoPost = new JSONObject();

        variablesMetodoPost.put("nombres", TextoNombres.getText().toString());
        variablesMetodoPost.put("apellidos", TextoApellidos.getText().toString());
        variablesMetodoPost.put("cedula", TextoCedula.getText().toString());
        variablesMetodoPost.put("telefono_1", TextoTelefono1.getText().toString());
        variablesMetodoPost.put("telefono_2", TextoTelefono2.getText().toString());
        variablesMetodoPost.put("direccion", TextoDirecion.getText().toString());

        Log.e("params", variablesMetodoPost.toString());
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(obtenerDatosStringAEnviar(variablesMetodoPost));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        //nos conectamos enviando el metodo de conexion y las variables
        //obtenemos una respuesta
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("respuesta", "la respuesta es: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        //convertimos el flujo de entrada en texto
        respuestaComoString = readIt(is, len);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        //se asegura de que el InputStream se cierra despues de la aplicacion y
        //es terminado de utilizar
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    return respuestaComoString;
}

public String obtenerDatosStringAEnviar(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        String key = itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;

        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();

}
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char [len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);

}

public void inicio(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

}
```

En el debut del emulador tengo esto:

`I/URL: http://naikino.com/pizzeria/php/registrar.php
E/params: {"nombres":"mauricio","apellidos":"vergara","cedula":"1024502218","telefono_1":"1234567","telefono_2":"1234689","direccion":"calle calle"}
D/respuesta: la respuesta es: 200
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f475bca36c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS`

Comment: Es demasiado amplio. Deberías, ya que no te origina error, hacer algun tipo de traza o debug para saber que está pasando y dar mas informacion

Comment: Por favor, [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/35053/edit) tu pregunta para que contenga toda la informacion relevante. no lo pongas en los comentarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas agregando las variables al BufferedWriter y no a la petición:

```
writer.write(obtenerDatosStringAEnviar(variablesMetodoPost));
```

Si usas `HttpUrlConnection` los valores deben agregarse a una lista de `NameValuePair` para ser enviados mediante `POST` , ejemplo:

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();
```

Comment: no puede resolver símbolo NameValuePair androide!

Según veo en la web deberia agregarlos al gradle e importar?

Comment: Usa compileSdkVersion 23.